# JSF2: navigation flow question

Tags: java, web-applications, jsf, jsf-2

I am not sure if what I want is possible, but it worth a try to ask. Let say, I have 2 pages: `List.jsf` and `CreateNew.jsf`. `List.jsf` display data from datasource as `<p:dataTable>`. `CreateNew.jsf` insert a new entry into the datasource. What I want is from `CreateNew.jsf`, when I click create, it create a new entry in a database, then return back to `List.jsf`, but at this point `List.jsf` somehow refresh itself so that new entry will be displayed as well. Is it possible to achieve it? Couples thing worth to note: Managed bean for `List.jsf` is `SessionScoped` and the managed bean for `CreateNew.jsf` is `RequestScoped`

Navigation flow in handle inside `faces-config.xml`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either change the `@SessionScoped` bean associated with `List.jsf` to be `@ViewScoped` so that a new one is constructed, *or* add a method like `reloadList()` to the `@SessionScoped` bean, inject that as `@ManagedProperty` into the `@RequestScoped` bean and let it call that method after creating the new entry.

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you :D I know the solution about switch to `ViewScoped`, just want to be a bit fancier. But create `reloadList()` is definitely a way to go. TY